# UR5 velocity control and trajectory recording/replaying

Tags: ros, moveit, velocity, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I have the following two issues to solve:

#1
I would like to control the velocity of the path execution of the UR5 robot. At the moment, I'm using the UR5 ROS-Industrial driver and MoveIt!. In the test_move.py of UR driver I've found a velocity vector, which is somehow looking like 'velocities=[0]*6'.
In my application I would like to call the velocity function in C++ or Python code. Maybe someone could tell me how to use or call the velocity functions for path planning and executing.

#2
The second issue is, that I would like to record and replay a trajectory, which was calculated by the MoveIt! pathplanning. The idea behind this is to recall the existing trajectory instead of calculating it every time for a well known path.
Solutions, which came into my mind are to record a bagfile for trajectory topic or to use the MongoDB. I'm not sure if this approach is the correct one. Particularly, I don't want to set up a database to record a trajectory in case of MongoDB. A single data file containing the trajectory values would be suitable for my issue.

Thanks for helping in advance. You will also find this post in the ROS-I mailinglist, but after quite some time of waiting I din't get any answers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204042/ur5-velocity-control-and-trajectory-recording/replaying/) by [NRW_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/21591/nrw_ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-03-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Carollour](https://answers.ros.org/users/21953/carollour/) on 2015-10-29**:
Were you able to find a solution for #2?

**Comment by [NRW_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/21591/nrw_ros/) on 2015-11-11**:
Sadly not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I would like to control the velocity of the path execution of the UR5 robot.

Do you want to specify velocity constraints on path segments, or are you after actual velocity control (ie: control joint velocity instead of position)?

<del>If the former: that is already supported, and should be specified in the trajectory that is send to the [control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryAction](http://docs.ros.org/api/control_msgs/html/action/FollowJointTrajectory.html) Action server setup by the `ur_driver`.</del> I just remembered: the current `ur_driver` does not actually use the `velocity` field in a `JointTrajectoryPoint`. Velocity (and also acceleration) are derived from the `time_from_start` field each `JointTrajectoryPoint` contains.

If the latter: the current ROS-Industrial driver for UR doesn't expose the velocity control functionality of the UR controller yet. There is however work ongoing to open up that interface for use from ROS. In the mean-time, you might want to look at alternatives, such as [urx](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/urx).

---

> Actually, I want to specify the velocity on path segment like you described in your first solution. I’ve found the `time_from_start` in the `JointTrajectoryPoint` Message. But how to use and set velocity values properly?

Isn't `time_from_start` automatically calculated (and then recalculated in `ur_driver`)? Afaicr I've never had to set those fields manually. Especially not when using MoveIt. If you do need to set it by hand, then `time_from_start` for point `n` should be the time at which the previous segment should be finished. So for a distance `x` (whatever 'distance' means in your particular case) and velocity `v`, `time_from_start` for point `n+1` should be (`time_from_start` for `n`) + `x/v`, if I'm not mistaken (see also [Moving the arm using the Joint Trajectory Action - 1.4: The trajectory message](http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Moving%20the%20arm%20using%20the%20Joint%20Trajectory%20Action#The_trajectory_message)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NRW_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/21591/nrw_ros/) on 2015-03-04**:
Actually, I want to specify the velocity on path segment like you described in your first solution. I’ve found the `time_from_start` in the `JointTrajectoryPoint` Message. But how to use and set velocity values properly?

**Comment by [NRW_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/21591/nrw_ros/) on 2015-03-04**:
ATM Im using the `MoveGroupInterface` from MoveIt! and `computeCartesianPath` function for calculating a path. To get a trajectory I’m using `robot_trajectory::RobotTrajectory` and `IterativeParabolicTimeParameterization` to fill the trajectory with velocity values.Afterwards, Im executing the path.

**Comment by [homesick-nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/25641/homesick-nick/) on 2016-08-05**:
Hello all, Late to the party but I'm also very interested to understand how to do velocity control. Specifically I would like to be able to execute a constant linear velocity. Changing the time from start only affects average velocity. Is there a way round this that anyone knows of? Cheers

**Comment by [araujokth](https://answers.ros.org/users/27769/araujokth/) on 2016-08-17**:
Hi, did you find a solution for #1? I was wanting to do velocity control of the tip of the UR5 robot, but if I understood your question correctly, that is not possible to be done?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-08-18**:
The [ur_modern_driver](https://github.com/ThomasTimm/ur_modern_driver) does expose a velocity interface to the UR controller via a ROS topic, but it currently only supports this in joint space. You could perhaps use the `/ur_driver/URScript` topic to send `speedl(..)` commands directly.